# Excel formula named range changes - Jan 2020 update

Tags: excel, excel-formula

UPDATE TO THE BELOW

The update has now rolled out to lots of machines, and broken maybe 90% of the work we have done in the past. Just to clarify exactly what I mean:

Using VBA (or C# or anything else for that matter) - we dynamically insert formulas at runtime using named ranges. For example:

=(MIN(Bid_S1,Bid_S2, Bid_S3, Bid_S4, Bid_S5)/Bid_S3)*PriceWeighting

This now longer works and gives a SPILL error. When I try to put the @ in front as suggested, I see a message telling me @  is not supported for some versions of Excel, do I still want to use it.

Option 1 - yes, I put @'s in front of every named range, spill error.
Option 2 - the formula they suggest is identical to the one I already had. Same Spill error.

This is going to be a huge problem for a lot of companies, surely.

Hard not to agree with this question:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/the-new-dynamic-arrays-spill-functionality-should/92f9847f-deca-4ec9-ada3-9e005a5b68da?rtAction=1579696000111&page=1

---

A very bizarre situation. 4 different computers. Each running identical versions of Excel, Windows.

A simple named range with 4 cells say, called PlanID

```
PlanID
1
2
3
4
```

Type "=PlanID" next to the first, on 3 of the machines it returns 1, as I would expect. On the 4th machine it returns the formula array of the whole range. Just spent about 2 hours researching Spill errors etc but nothing seems to directly relate to the 2 issues I have:

1. How can something that has worked reliably for years suddenly not work
2. Why only on one machine?

Literally identical versions of Excel (16.0.12325.20280 32 bit)

Comment: One has the new dynamic array formula and the other does not.  Excel has introduced the ability to put an array in multiple cells with only one formula in the first cell and Excel will "Spill" the data down.

Comment: I don't understand how this is an answer. Why does one machine behave differently to the other 3? And why would something so basic be changed? Anyone that ever referenced a range name in this way needs to change their formulas?

Comment: @ScottCraner  When was this introduced ?

Comment: Machine 4 suddenly broke end Nov. The point I am most interested in finding out what "One has the new dynamic array formula" actually means. Given they all have the same version of Excel

Comment: @Gary'sStudent it depends on ones update schedule.  For those insiders it has been over a year.  For others it is being rolled out over 6 months.

Comment: So to confirm, it is now completely impossible to reference a named range by saying ="NamedRange" if that range has more than one row?

Comment: @JpadSolutions no, one just needs to understand that one should have always used index on named ranges from the start and not rely on relative row to return the correct number of a range.  `=INDEX(PlanID,1)` The use of Index to insure that the correct item in the array is chosen is good practice and should have been used from the beginning.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am saying. Are you seriously suggesting people should have written formulas that span, say 10,000 rows, using a named range that way?

Comment: For example:

=SUMIF(MonthlyCbnPlanID,PlanID,MonthlyCbnNetAdj)

Where PlanID is similar to my example in the question. Inserted dynamically into 10,000 rows. You are suggesting one should program that to say Index(PlanID, row number) and that is good practise?

Comment: How are you using the named range?  Are you putting `=PlanID` in a cell then dragging it down?  Are you highlighting for cells them putting in the formula and using CSE to populate?

Comment: I am adding formulas from code. The great beauty being if you name all your ranges correctly you can very easily do this. Now... not so much, apparently. I am still very interested in the difference between the machines. Are you saying that the same exact version number can be on all but them still be different? (for 2 months+) ?

Comment: Now instead of having to drag down the formula or using cse you only need to put the formula in the first cell and Excel will spill the results.  If you only wanted the first value in the array then yes you should have used INDEX() from the beginning to ensure the correct number was used.  As to the version number I do not know, but a quick test is to see if they have `SORT()` or `FILTER()` functions on their worksheet.

Comment: I think there is some confusion. The result should only be (was only) one number. This is not an array formula. Previously if you entered a formula such as: "=Range 1 * Range 2" it would multiply the values on the row by each other. Now it spills.

Comment: `"=Range 1 * Range 2"` would only multiply the first row, not the second or third unless you copied the formula down or selected multiple cells and copied them down.  `SUMPRODUCT(Range 1 * Range 2) would multiply all the cells in both ranges and sum them.

Comment: Exactly yes. I am putting a formula into every cell. My example is over simplified. But say:

something * Range 1 * Range 2 + something else where I am dynamically changing the "somethings" at runtime. But now range 1 * range 2 does not just multiply the first row. It errors

Comment: Then yes I stand by that one should have used Index to avoid the confusion and possible errors allowing Excel to assume which item in the array should be used and where.  There is an article out there that talks about this, and how it can cause problems, I can't find it right now, but the jest was assuming that Excel will accurately return the correct cell from the named range without Index is too trusting and may lead to incorrect returns.

Comment: Not trying to be disagreeable but it doesn't make any sense to me. The whole point of named ranges, is that you don't have to hard code a reference. Why would I Want to put index,1 ... index,2 in my formulas. As soon as anyone moves any data they are then returning incorrect values.

Comment: How so? INDEX() uses relative numbering.  `INDEX(PlanID,3)` would return the third value no matter where `PlanID` was located.

Comment: Because if I moved PlanID3 data to be in position 2, the existing formula would have still returned the correct answer (as it does on 3 machines now) whereas the other way it would not. Which seems inherently very dangerous to me?

Comment: Anyways, I guess my opinion isn't hugely relevant. What is relevant is if this is genuinely going to be rolled out worldwide, lots of things are going to break. Having worked in large companies as an Excel dev for 20 odd years, a lot of stuff is going to break and need rewriting. I just thought I must be seeing things. I guess not.

Comment: Re your update: perhaps if you post a proper verifiable example of your current approach,  and how Dynamic Arrays break it, we may be able to suggest a workable solution.   Probably best done as a  new Q.

Answer (score 0):

Sound to me like your exisiting worksheets rely on Implicit Intersection (whether you realised it or not).

If that's the case, you can continue to use that, by preceeding your formula with `@` ([See here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34) )

If you create a workbook in a version of Excel that supports Dynamic Arrays, you will need to be explicit with your Implicit Inersections.

If you create a workbook in a version of Excel that does *not* support DA's, then later open it in a version that does, Excel will insert the `@`'s for you.

To illustrate, here's a book created in a version that does *not* support DA's

[image]

Here's the same workbook opened (without modification) in a version that *does* support DA's

[image]

Note the addition of `@`'s in the selected formula